# How do I disable a click function when clicked to allow form text input clicking?

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I have a div that when clicked opens a form inside the div via jquery .click function.

This works great until I need to click inside the form on text inputs! Doh!

How can I disable the click function when this particular div is "open" (i.e. the form is showing). And then return the click function when the div is "closed" again?

Comment: [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)  But without seeing any of your markup or code, it's going to be difficult to suggest much more than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asusming an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="outer_clicking_div">
    <div id="form_div">
        <!-- form here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Your just need to stop propogation of clicks above the form div like this

```
$('#form_div').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get e.stopPropagation() to work.  Ultimately one() worked for me thought.  Thanks.  Marking this as answer because question very limited, without code, and you gave it a shot anyway.  (I asked from an airplane from my phone when I was frustrated I couldn't figure it out before taking off - so that's why there wasn't code)  Anyway, thanks again.